# Cumulative sum of specific keys with array output using reduce

Tags: javascript, object, functional-programming

Say I have the following array:

```
let arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: -1}]
```

I would like to compute the cumulative sum of each key, but I would also like the output to be an array of the same length with the cumulative values at each step. The final result should be:

```
[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 6}, {a: 11, b: 5}]
```

My issue is that I am not able to obtain the array as desired. I only get the final object with this:

```
let result = arr.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
  if(accumulator.length === 0) {
    accumulator = element
  } else {
    for(let i in element){
      accumulator[i] = accumulator[i] + element[i]
    }
  }
  return accumulator
}, [])

console.log(result); // {a: 11, b: 5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: -1}]

const result = arr.reduce((accumulator, element, index) => {
  if(accumulator.length === 0) {
    accumulator.push(element)
  } else {
    const sum = {};
    for(let i in element) {
      sum[i] = element[i] + (accumulator[index - 1][i] || 0)
    }
    accumulator.push(sum)
  }
  return accumulator
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Another option is keep sum result using a `Map`, it helps if keys in elements of the array are not always same.

```js
const arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2}, {a: 8, b: -1}];
const map = new Map();
const result = arr.map((element) => {
  const sum = {};
  for (let i in element) {
    sum[i]= element[i] + (map.get(i) || 0);
    map.set(i, sum[i]);
  }
  return sum;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're after sounds like the `scan()` higher-order function (borrowing the idea from [ramda.js](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#scan)), which allows you to return an accumulated result for each element within your array. The scan method is similar to how the `.reduce()` method behaves, except that it returns the accumulator for each element. You can build the `scan()` function yourself like so:

```js
let arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: -1}];

const scan = ([x, ...xs], fn) => xs.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  return [...acc, fn(acc.at(-1), elem)];
}, xs.length ? [x] : []);

const res = scan(arr, (x, y) => ({a: x.a+y.a, b: x.b+y.b}));
console.log(res);
```

You might consider further improvements such as providing an initial value to the scan method (similar to how reduce accepts one). Also, if you need better browser support the [`.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method currently has limited browser support, so you may instead consider creating your own `at()` function:

```js
const at = (arr, idx) => idx >= 0 ? arr[idx] : arr[arr.length + idx];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve the  result using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as

```js
let arr = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 2, b: 4 },
  { a: 8, b: -1 },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  if (i === 0) acc.push(curr);
  else {
    const last = acc[i - 1];
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(curr).forEach((k) => (newObj[k] = curr[k] + last[k]));
    acc.push(newObj);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit more concise reduce, probably not as readable as a consequence...

```
array.reduce((y,x,i) => ( i===0 ? y : [...y, {a: x.a + y[i-1].a, b: x.b + y[i-1].b}]),[array[0]])
```

```js
let array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: -1}]
let culm = array.reduce((y,x,i) => ( i===0 ? y : [...y, {a: x.a + y[i-1].a, b: x.b + y[i-1].b}]),[array[0]])
console.log(culm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```js
const xs =
  [ {a: 1, b:  2}
  , {a: 2, b:  4}
  , {a: 8, b: -1}];
```

Define a function `sum` such as:

```js
const sum = ([head, ...tail]) =>
  tail.reduce((x, y) =>
    ({a: (x.a+y.a), b: (x.b+y.b)}), head);

sum(xs);
//=> {a: 11, b: 5}
```

Then apply that function in a map on larger slices of `xs`:

```js
xs.map((_, i, arr) => sum(arr.slice(0, i+1)));
//=> [ {a:  1, b: 2}
//=> , {a:  3, b: 6}
//=> , {a: 11, b: 5}]
```